# Differences between overloay and underlay in Apptainer

Tags: mount, container, bind-mount

I'm trying to understand the differences between the two ways of bindings filesystems in Apptainer configuration. The documentation can be found [here](https://apptainer.org/docs/admin/latest/configfiles.html#supplemental-filesystems), but here are the confusing parts:

> enable overlay: This option will allow Apptainer to create bind mounts at paths that do not exist within the container image. This option can be set to try (the default), which will try to use an overlayfs. If it fails to create an overlayfs in this case the bind path will be silently ignored. If the option is set to yes then if overlayfs fails in SUID mode it will be a fatal error, but if overlayfs fails in non-SUID mode it will use fuse-overlayfs. **Underlay is more efficient than fuse-overlayfs so setting this option to yes is generally not desirable.**

> enable underlay: This option will allow Apptainer to create bind mounts at paths that do not exist within the container image, just like enable overlay, but instead using an underlay. **This is suitable for systems where overlay is not possible or not working.** If the overlay option is available and working, it will be used instead.

Basically what I understand is that underlay is more efficient than overlay and should be used (first bold part), but also that underlay is only a replacement for when overlay is not available (second bold part).

So basically I have two questions:

- what are the differences under the hood? This [issue on Github](https://github.com/apptainer/singularity/issues/1207) kind of explained how underlay works, but it is not clear and does not talk much about how overlay works.
- which one should be preferred and in when the other one should be used?